# Incorrect measurements with Arduino HX711 and cc2541 Bluetooth module

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using Arduino Nano with HX711 scales module and cc2541 Bluetooth module(Bluetooth 4.0) to send data to Android device.

```
#define RX 11
#define TX 10

#include "HX711.h"

HX711 scale(A1, A0);

float scale_calibration = -13.5;
float mass,massround;
float units;

int out;

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(TX, RX);

void setup()
{
  bluetooth.begin(9600);

  scale.set_scale();
  scale.tare();
  scale.set_scale(scale_calibration);
}

void loop()
{

  for(int i = 0;i < 10; i ++) units =+ scale.get_units(), 1;

  units / 10;
  mass = units * 0.035274; 
  massround=mass;
  out = round(massround);
  out = abs(out);

  if(out<0)
  {
    out=0;
    scale.tare();
  }
  bluetooth.println(out);

}
```

If I run Arduino using USB coonected to my PC, the scales work perfect and give right results via Bluetooth. However, when I run Arduino using battery (not connected to PC), I get 0-3 grams value, while there is nothing on the scales. So because of that all measurements are incorrect. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When your Arduino is powered from USB, it and the HX711 probably have both VCC and VDD at +5 volts, making the 'reference' voltage (VDD) 5 volts. 
When running off battery, the hardware is receiving ~3 volts, and if VCC and VDD are shorted together on the HX711, it might 'kinda work' but would give spurious results.

There's probably jumpers or bridges to set VCC and VDD on both the arduino and the load cell. CAUTION! I'm just guessing here, and be sure to read the tech docs before changing the voltage settings, it's easy to cook these little circuits with a minor change in voltages.

This might be better asked in a hardware or electrical engineering channel.